# when category is not null then return record accordingly categoryID. When categoryID is null then all record return

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

```
SELECT TOP (@NoofQuetion) 
    *
FROM 
    tblQuestion qs
WHERE
    qs.IsActive = 1 
    AND qs.IsDeleted = 0 
    OR (qs.CategoryID IS NULL AND qs.CategoryID = @CategoryId) 
ORDER BY 
    NEWID()
```

In this query, `@NoofQuestion` is is limit apply on record. I want when `categoryId IS NULL` in where condition then given record all type of `categoryId`. And when `@CategoryId` is passed as a parameter, return rows with a matching `categoryId` only.

For example I pass `@CategoryId = 2`, I get only record where

```
ISACTIVE = 1 AND ISDELETED = 0 AND CategoryID = 2
```

When I pass `NULL` as `@CategoryId`, then return all rows where

```
ISACTIVE = 1 AND ISDELETED = 0
```

Give me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You swapped the `OR` and `AND`. Your `WHERE` statement should look like

```sql
qs.IsActive = 1 AND qs.IsDeleted = 0 AND (qs.CategoryID IS NULL OR qs.CategoryID = @CategoryId)
```

**EDIT**:

After some testing, it turns out there's a second problem in your `WHERE` clause. You're checking if the `CategoryId` in the table is null, not if your `@CategoryId` variable is null. After this change and the change mentioned above, your `WHERE` clause should look like

```sql
qs.IsActive = 1 AND qs.IsDeleted = 0 AND (@CategoryID IS NULL OR qs.CategoryID = @CategoryId)
```

[Here's the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/addfb/11) I used to test it.

Comment: I apply this Condition when I pass 2 then given record Having @category = 2 when I pass Null then Not return any record.

Comment: That's not what you said in your question. Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: This is the correct answer according to your question.

Comment: This query give zero record when i pass null

Comment: I found the other problem. Refer to the edits in the answer.